# Which format of authentication would be most efficient for human memory?

Tags: memory, long-term-memory

**Introduction:**

There are many ways to authenticate when it comes to data access: passwords, numeric PIN-s, visual passwords, gestures, etc.

A common form of authentication, an 8-character password over all 95 ASCII chars, would contain ~53 bits of entropy ($95^8$ possibilities).

A password in the top 1000 most common passwords would contain only ~10 bits of entropy (1000 possibilities), but would be easier to remember.

A 4-word passphrase over 10'000 most common words would also contain ~53 bits of entropy ($10'000^4$ possibilities), but would maybe(?) be easier to remember than 8 random characters.

**Presumption:**

My question is based on the assumption that same amount of information represented in different formats (sound, image, text, song, movement, etc.) are not equally easy to remember. Maybe passwords (or text based methods in general) are not the best option.

**Question:**

In which format, can humans memorize the largest amount of information and present it to a computer device? I'd be glad if you could link some relevant research, too.

Comment: Years ago, [XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png) said it best. Anyone can easily remember a short phrase or list of words.  Memorizing 8 characters is much more difficult, especially when there are pointless rules requiring special characters.